# Remove efficiently the last zeros in a list of integers (c# or vb.net)

Tags: c#, vb.net, list, trim

I am removing the rightmost zeros in a list of integers (they can only be 0 or 1) as follows:

```
For i As Integer = Product.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If Product(i) = 0 Then
        Product.RemoveAt(i)
    Else
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Could you suggest a solution less awkward and possibly more efficient of what I am currently doing.

If possible I'd like also to see an alternative solution for preserving 1 zero, if the list contains 1 zero and 1 zero only. Thank you (language, c# of vb.net is immaterial).

(PS. Note that "efficiency", which is part of the question, is an objective criterion, not based on opinions.)

Comment: In terms of efficiency, there's not much more you can do. Your solution is already O(n) and you can't do better than that. As for elegance, that's highly subjective..

Comment: What does "removing the rightmost zeros" mean?  From your code, it looks like you just want the 1's?

Comment: It looks fine to me though assuming this is encapsulated into a single method. Anything else is going to be purely syntactic sugar.

Comment: @Khan I just wish to remove the 0s from the right before encountering the first 1 (see the exit for). The list comes out from a "product", and the lsb bit is stored on the left. So the zeros on the right are useless. Clearly, if there is only 1 zero (product=0) (special case), I'd like to keep it.

Comment: Your solution is already O(n) and I understood it even though my understanding of vb.net is minimal, that implies readability is good and it appears elegant to me even. Please do not underestimate your solution. You may get many answers for this but as for efficiency your algo will trump all.

Comment: Thank you @Abhi. It's kind to hear. In the meantime I can see a lot of interesting proposals are arriving and I will study them all with interest. In my code above the for could run to 1 instead of 0 to "preserve" the case when product = 0. Later I will mark the answer with larger consensus from you experts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do this:

```
public void RemoveTrailingZeros( List<int> digits )
{
  int i = digits.Count ;
  while ( --i >= 0 && digits[i] == 0 )
  {
    digits.RemoveAt(i) ;
  }
  return ;
}
```

Even tidier:

```
static void RemoveTrailingZeroes( List<int> digits )
{
  int i = 1 + digits.FindLastIndex( x => x != 0 ) ;
  digits.RemoveRange(i,digits.Count-i) ;
  return ;
}
```

Comment: This seems to be removing even the zeros 'inside' the number represented by the list. no ?

Comment: No, this will exit the loop as soon as it hits a non-zero digit. It works, but isn't any more elegant or clean than the original solution in my opinion (though it avoids the "early break")

Comment: ah ok. I get it. To "preserve" the case product = 0, it is sufficient to replace the first 0 with 1, right ?

Comment: @LordTakkera: it avoids the gratuitous if-then-else construct in the loop body.

Comment: @Nicholas. Right. Actually, it seems pretty elegant. Perhaps the only "criticism" possible is that perhaps (?) it's a bit "language dependent", in the sense that I am not sure this could be "rendered", for instance, in vb.net (can we decrease the index in the while clause in vb.net?).

Comment: @Pam, that change would do as you requested. Changing it to strictly greater than would accomplish the same purpose. This solution is basically the same as the original (with the if-else replaced by making it a while loop, which is better practice). Otherwise it shares the same performance and "elegance" characteristics, hence my comment.

Comment: @Nicholas wow. I was wrong: I just tried. It works in vb.net too! Beautiful  :-)

Comment: Thank you for the addition @Nicholas, I just noticed it

Comment: @Nicholas Just a curiosity, isn't the first one of your proposals, the most efficient one ? I would guess so

Comment: I'd imagine so, given that `List<T` uses an array as its backing store, but I can't say I've actually looked at it.

Answer (score 3):

If the values can only be 0 or 1, you could search for the last 1 and remove everything after that.

```
    Dim index As Integer
    index = Product.LastIndexOf(1) + 1
    Product.RemoveRange(index, Product.Count - index)
```

If the list only contains 0 the index will be equal to 0, so you could add an if statment right before the RemoveRange.

```
    Dim index As Integer
    index = Product.LastIndexOf(1) + 1
    If index = 0 Then index = 1
    Product.RemoveRange(index, Product.Count - index)
```

(This might crash if there are no items in the list)

**Update**

Since it's searching for 1, the index of the first 0 will be the index returned +1. This also fix the issue of the function returning -1 when it's all zeros.

Comment: Neat method! According to MSDN, LastIndexOf returns -1 if not found (not 0).

Comment: @LordTakkera I add +1 after the LastIndexOf so it'll be 0.

Comment: You are right (just saw that :) ). You may want to consider adding that to your explanation, because reading it I assumed 0 was not found, and it took careful examination of the code to determine that it was otherwise.

Comment: Added some more info for that.

Comment: +0 so far: I don't think it is as readable as original - maybe adding explicit check for `if (lastIndex <= 1) return;` to keep single 0 in the list would make code more explicit... Random-looking `+1` in the code are always concerning...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov If +1 is not added then RemoveRange will also remove the last "1" from the list.

Comment: I'm not saying it is producing wrong results (it look correct), but it does not make intention of the code clear. `+1` feels like random hack rather than well placed code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure its any more elegant, but it does use LINQ!

```
int lastOne = i.IndexOf(i.Last(n => n == 1));
List<int> trimmedList = i.Take(lastOne + 1); //Account for zero-based index
```

To get the single zero, I would use LastOrDefault

```
int lastOne = i.IndexOf(i.LastOrDefault(n => n == 1));
List<int> trimmedList = i.Take(lastOne + 1); //Account for zero-based index
```

By far the "coolest" LINQ method, as suggested by Alexi Levenkov:

```
Reverse().SkipWhile(i=> i==0).Reverse();
```

This will remove the single zero case, in which case I would use a ternary:

```
i.All(n => n == 0) ? i.Take(1) : i.Reverse().SkipWhile(i=> i==0).Reverse();
```

Comment: Very interesting Lord. Thank you

Comment: +1... Warning: I'm not sure I like my suggestion with `Reverse` anymore :) - it should be used strictly for education/entrainment purposes - `Reverse.Skip.Reverse` is possible to read, but with special case for `Count()==1` I'd spend too much time trying to read it.

Comment: Agreed that the reverse method isn't as readable as the others. It still has "cool" points though :)

Answer (score -2):

Just trim :)

```
Product.TrimEnd('0');
```

Comment: This works for a string, not a list of ints as in the question.

Comment: Thank you anyway for the try Anton.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @stephenbayer, its an incorrect answer, granted, but I wouldn't say its not an *attempt* at an answer.

Comment: oops, for reason I thought it was a string. Sorry.